# zheev outputs incorrect and random results when called from within dynamic library

Tags: fortran, lapack, intel-mkl, memory-corruption

I have DFT(density functional theory) code written in Fortran. Inside this program I use `zheev` function from lapack to diagonalize overlap matrix (S). I compile the code in two different targets (a) standalone program `fireball.x` and (b) dynamic library (`libFireCore.so`), without any differences in the code.

When I run the program `fireball.x` everything works fine.
When I call `libFireCore.so` from inside other program (written in C++) it produces incorect output which is non-deterministic - i.e. every time I run it I got different results.

I tracked down the problem, and it turns out the problem is in some  `zheev` call where I diagonalize overlap matrix.

When I print the overlap matrix (S) which goes into `zheev` it is exactly the same (in `fireball.x` and `libFireCore.so`). But the output matrix (eigenvectors, zzzz) differ at the end. (see attached images)

The S matrix which goes in is the same:
[image]

The eigenvectros (zzzz) which goes out differs at the end:
[image]

At the same time the eigenvaues are exactly the same (and the values are not crazy small or crazy large):
S-eigenvalues:   0.20320429171825077       0.23871180664043531       0.24800955043297762       0.25981763454707818       0.26625761411873500       0.29656130959541332       0.30406932675113513       0.31931361483751519       0.34177021310844230       0.36133697610296117       0.38357717267479940       0.57800206110211672       0.73150940647530815       0.73986354541136745       0.87968589806449793        1.0629166543759208        1.1745454410259122        1.1914134775739986        1.2071693499296059        1.2928315521982148        1.3497098021371781        1.4298908216838513        1.5846592240498847        1.7381615303550286        1.9139531841288968        1.9292327889682286        2.1528696122119046        2.2187686011872194        2.6022345485931204

How is this possible? It seems like some memory corruption inside `zheev` or how else I can explain the randomness of output (non-deterministic)?

I checked using `MKL_VERBOS=1` that the version of MKL library is the same as well as the dimensions of all arrays (including the temporary work-arrays) is the same. So what can be wrong?

```
    integer lwork, lrwork, liwork
    complex, allocatable, dimension (:) :: work
    real,    allocatable, dimension (:) :: rwork
    real,    allocatable, dimension (:) :: slam
    complex, allocatable, dimension (:, :)    :: xxxx, zzzz

    allocate ( slam(norbitals) )
    allocate ( xxxx(norbitals,norbitals) )
    allocate ( zzzz(norbitals,norbitals) )

    lwork  = 1
    lrwork = 3*norbitals - 2
    allocate (work(lwork))
    allocate (rwork(lrwork))

    write (*,*) "!!!! DEBUG sqrtS debug_writeMatFile(Sk_sqrtS.log) norbitals=",norbitals, ' lwork = ',lwork, ' lrwork = ',lrwork, ' liwork = ',liwork, ' divide = ',divide
    call debug_writeMatFile_cmp( "Sk_sqrtS_", zzzz, norbitals, norbitals, 0 )

        slam(:)  = 0.0d0
        work (:) = 0.0d0
        rwork(:) = 0.0d0

! first find optimal working space size (lwork)
        call zheev ('V', 'U', norbitals, zzzz, norbitals, slam, work,   -1, rwork, info)
! resize working space
        lwork = work(1)    !  workspace query see: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d9a/group__complex16_h_eeigen_gaf23fb5b3ae38072ef4890ba43d5cfea2.html

        deallocate (work)
        allocate (work(lwork))
! diagonalize the overlap matrix with the new working space

        slam(:)  = 0.0d0
        work (:) = 0.0d0
        rwork(:) = 0.0d0
        call zheev ('V', 'U', norbitals, zzzz, norbitals, slam, work,  lwork, rwork , info)

    if (info .ne. 0) call diag_error (info, 0)

    write (*,*) "!!!! DEBUG sqrtS() debug_writeMatFile(zzzz_pre.log) norbitals=",norbitals, " norbitals_new= ", norbitals_new, "info ", info
    call debug_writeMatFile_cmp( "zzzz_pre1_", zzzz, norbitals, norbitals, 0 )
```

**EDIT**

I found the problem/solution. It is about OpenMP. When I switch OpenMP off in compiler, or if **I set `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` it works just fine.**

It seems similar to this problem:
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/Incorrect-eigenvectors-from-ZHEEV-in-MKL-using-multi-threading/td-p/836860

Still it would be nice if somebody can give me some advice why OpenMP cause problem here, and how to solve it. I would like to use OpenMP in my application.

Comment: zheev is for (in old speak) double complex. You are using default kind complex. They are not the same thing. You should probably be calling cheev. This may be changed if you are using compiler flags to change the default real kind. If you are, don't unless you want to live a life full of pain.

Comment: To say anything more is a guess (e.g. You have got `Implicit None`, haven't you?). What we really need is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The above is not enough.

Comment: Note also complex eigenvectors have an arbitrary phase. You can get apparently total different evecs which are actually both totally valid solutions to the problem. And there is no guarantee that a eigenproblem solver will give the same variant, and note this is not just for degenerate cases. Simply comparing evecs is not enough, you have to check the Eval equation is satisfied if you are checking for correctness

Comment: @IanBush  yes, I have set default real to double in compiler flags.

Comment: @IanBush clearly I cannot provide *minimal, reproducible example* because the problem is clearly context dependent - the same source code when run as standalone executable was working fine, while when called as a function from library was not working fine. Now I found that the difference in context was the `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10` vs `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`. But that is something I could not know beforehand.

Comment: @IanBush I was not so much checking for correctness, but rather checking where the execution deviates. I had the same code compiled in two targets, One was deterministic and working (i.e. [SCFcycle](https://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/webprojects2002/grant/webcomp/scf.html) was converging , and in the other was not converging and producing  no-deterministic resuts (different molecular orbital every run)

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic produce different accumulated round-off errors depending on which order the operations are performed, and this is often what happens when using multithreading. I can't tell if it's enough to explain the differences you are observing, though. Just, generally speaking, round-off errors can results in large differences in poorly conditioned problems.

Comment: Fair enough, but as @PierU points out different round off will cause different phases but correct answers. Just looking at the evecs and saying they are different is not enough. But over and above all that calling zheev with single precision complex is a bug. You need to correct that before anything else

Comment: Oh. You've used compiler and flags. All bets are off then.